# How does NGINX Plus handle server failure when doing session persistence for TCP/UDP communication?

Tags: nginx, tcp, failover, udp, sticky-sessions

My understanding from the NGINX Plus documentation is that their Load Balancing will route around servers that are down or swamped and that Session Persistence attempts to maintain the same server for a given session. It feels like the two might become mutually exclusive when a server goes down mid-sessions. Is there an indication of the server failure, so that we know that there might be some data loss due to switching to another server (which might not have in the in-session changes) or does it switch over quietly?

This is specifically for TCP/UDP communication, not HTTP.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/session-persistence/ , But i recommended to use HAproxy to handling sessions.

Comment: @PersianGulf: That does indicate that session persistence is performed. It doesn't indicate how it works on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels like the two might become mutually exclusive

Yes. That's not a problem specific to nginx. By far the best solution is to have your session data replicated / highly available - but that's not easy to bolt on to an existing service that hasn't been well-planned.

What do you want nginx to do when the server implementing a session fails? Failover to any other other server? Failover to a specific server? Are your servers in pairs? something else? Stop the session - since it is in an indeterminant state....There are so many options.

As for reporting of failures. There are 2 parts to this. One is monitoring - someone needs to be told stuff is broken / needs fixed. This is not Nginx's job. That's for your monitoring stack to deal with. The second part is letting the client know that something hasn't worked. Nginx doesn't know it should put the stock back on the shelves / re-apply the DNS change. That's the job the protocol you are running and the application. While there are timing issues most network protocols use an exchange of short request/reply messages to provide visibility of server state at the client. In the case of (most) databases this is very well-defined with an explicit "COMMIT" message from the client. But consider what happens if the client says "COMMIT" and does not receive a reply?

> This is specifically for TCP/UDP communication, not HTTP.

Like @PersionGulf, I'd recomment using HAProxy for non-HTTP load balancing / HA of TCP over nginx. Last time I checked it can't do UDP.

> It doesn't indicate how it works on failure

It's not hard to test.